# питон не работает в командной строке windows 10

Tags: python, pip, pillow

устанавливал pillow через pip в командной строке, однако выдавало "pip не является.." Сам pip уже установлен, пробовал через командную строку установить этот же самый pip, но все питновские команды он не выполняет, никаких ошибок, просто пропускает строку. в path тоже все в порядке, все пути есть. версия  3.8.5

Answer (score 1):

Возможно дело в том, что нужно использовать pip3 вместо pip.

Comment: спасибо, а почему просто pip не срабатывает? в папке ведь pip, pip3 и pip3.8

Comment: Если честно,не знаю.Сижу на версии 3.6.5 и пип работает нормально, хотя в некоторых системах и версиях приходилось использовать пип3. Скорее всего особенность новых версий.